# Constructive Group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, constructive-mathematics

What would group theory look like in constructive mathematics? i.e. what results in group theory do we know it is impossible to prove constructively?

Comment: Most of the stuff in group theory, from quotient groups to Sylow p-subgroups, tend to be constructible for finite groups. Things start getting funny for uncountable groups.

Answer (score 2):

While finite groups are constructively well-behaved to my understanding, interesting phenomena arise when we look at the structure theory of *infinite* groups. For example, Lubarsky and Richman showed that Walker's cancellation theorem [fails constructively](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02137). However, this doesn't rule out weaker cancellation theorems holding constructively, and indeed their Theorem $5$ gives an example of one which does.